# How to resolve pgadmin 4 GRANT syntax error in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant

I am currently busy trying to execute some SQL queries form my demonstratie of a PostgreSQL/Postgis database. However I get a syntax on a certain line in my query.

This query did work in the past on a different computer so I do not see the problem here of why it does not work now:

```
CREATE ROLE demonstratieuser NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
CREATE ROLE demonstratieadmin NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT demonstratieuser TO demonstratieadmin
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE demodatabase TO demonstratieadmin
```

It is the following line that has the syntax error on more specifically the Grant part.

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE demodatabase TO demonstratieadmin
```

How do I fix this?

Edit error code:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GRANT"
LINE 4: GRANT ALL ON DATABASE demodatabase TO demonstratieadmin;
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "GRANT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 222
```

Comment: What is the error message? The obvious error is that you forgot to terminate the last two statements with a `;`

Comment: Error code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's cause you are missing a `;` semicolon in the below line which is line terminator.

```
GRANT demonstratieuser TO demonstratieadmin
```

So it should actually be

```
CREATE ROLE demonstratieuser NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
CREATE ROLE demonstratieadmin NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT demonstratieuser TO demonstratieadmin;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE demodatabase TO demonstratieadmin;
```